# Python Print only latest RSS feed items

Tags: python, for-loop, rss-reader

I'm using following code to get the items of an RSS feed. Unfortunately I'm not able to get only the latest three items.

```
import feedparser

feed = feedparser.parse('http://www.macstories.net/feed/')

for e in feed['entries']:
        print e.get('title','')
        print
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a close look at your feed:

```
items = feed['entries']

for item in items:
    print item['published']
```

Entries are already in DESC order, so you can simply grab the first few records:

```
items[0:3]
```